# data.table automatically coerces nested list to data.table when printing

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we have a list column in a `data.table`:

```
> dt = data.table( x = list( as.list( 1:4 ) ) )
> dt
        x
1: <list>
```

When I access the first index of `x` inside `dt` through `j`, `x` is automatically coerced into a `data.table`.

```
> dt[, x[[1]] ]
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  1  2  3  4
> dt
              x
1: <data.table>
```

This behaviour appears to occur only when accessing and printing as above. Alternative expressions for accessing or printing do not lead to the coercion:

```
> #Accessing only
> dt[, {z = x[[1]];NULL} ]
NULL
> dt
        x
1: <list>
> #Accessing and printing
> dt[, {z = x[[1]];print(z);NULL} ]
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

NULL
> dt
        x
1: <list>
```

Furthermore, when I access `x` outside of the `dt` environment, I do not get the coercion of `x` inside `dt`.

```
> dt[ , x ][[1]]
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

> dt
        x
1: <list>
```

I was just wondering if there is any way to prevent this automatic coercion? I have other `data.table`s with list columns in which some rows can be converted into a `data.table` while others have irregular numbers of elements such that they can only be `list`.

Comment: I think you have difficulty in understanding how a `list` and column of data.frame, data.table differ.  In your dataset, it is a list of list .  When you do the `x[[1]]`, you a get a `list` of 4 elements, but problem is that a data.frame or data.table is a `list` of vectors of equal length

Comment: It's a feature. We commonly use this, e.g., like this: `DT[, .(mean = mean(col))]`. Use `dt[["x"]][[1]]` in your case.